# PHP behavior with parenthesis and object members

Tags: php

Recently I was working with results from an SQL query call on a mysqli object. I wrote this line of code:

```
$record = ($result->fetch_object())->acc_id;
```

and i got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)` for that line.

Once i changed the code to this:

```
$record = $result->fetch_object()->acc_id;
```

it  worked as intended.

Why did the parenthesis induce a parse error? I know that in C# the former code would work regardless of them (accounting for the change in syntax)?

Comment: Limitation of PHP. You can not use the `->` on an evaluated expression.

Comment: Fwiw, in PHP 7 you can.

Comment: These seem to be good answers, someone should post it so I can choose it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @trincot Except for `(new Foo)->bar()`... PHP is full of special cases... -_-;;

Comment: yep, need to deal with it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by trincot:

> Limitation of PHP. You can not use the -> on an evaluated expression